# sed - Addressing using two strings

Tags: sed

I am picking up sed. I am having a trouble understanding how the line addressing in sed works when a pattern is used to specify line address.

I have a sample text file named `emp.lst` with the following contents:

```
2233|a.k. shukla      |g.m.     |sales     |12/12/52|6000
9876|jai sharma       |director |production|12/03/50|7000
5678|sumit chakrobarty|d.g.m.   |marketing |19/04/43|6000
2365|barun sengupta   |director |personnel |11/05/47|7800
5423|n.k. gupta       |chairman |admin     |30/08/56|5400
1006|chanchal singhvi |director |sales     |03/09/38|6700
6213|karuna ganguly   |g.m.     |accounts  |05/06/62|6300
1265|s.n. dasgupta    |manager  |sales     |12/09/63|5600
4290|jayant Choudhury |executive|production|07/09/50|6000
2476|anil aggarwal    |manager  |sales     |01/05/59|5000
6521|lalit chowdury   |director |marketing |26/09/45|8200
3212|shyam saksena    |d.g.m.   |accounts  |12/12/55|6000
3564|sudhir Agarwal   |executive|personnel |06/07/47|7500
2345|j.b. saxena      |g.m.     |marketing |12/03/45|8000
0110|v.k. agrawal     |g.m.     |marketing |31/12/40|9000
```

As I understand, line address can be specified either in the form of line number(s) of a pattern to match as text or regular expression.

I understand how `sed -n '1p' emp.lst` and `sed -n '1,2p' emp.lst` print line 1 and line 1 & 2 respectively without echoing all lines (`-n`).

I also understand and appreciate how `sed -n '/director/p' emp.lst` match all the lines containing the string `director`, and outputs:

```
9876|jai sharma       |director |production|12/03/50|7000
2365|barun sengupta   |director |personnel |11/05/47|7800
1006|chanchal singhvi |director |sales     |03/09/38|6700
6521|lalit chowdury   |director |marketing |26/09/45|8200
```

Now, when I specify multiple patters as `sed -n '/director/,/executive/p' emp.lst`, the output shown is:

```
9876|jai sharma       |director |production|12/03/50|7000
5678|sumit chakrobarty|d.g.m.   |marketing |19/04/43|6000
2365|barun sengupta   |director |personnel |11/05/47|7800
5423|n.k. gupta       |chairman |admin     |30/08/56|5400
1006|chanchal singhvi |director |sales     |03/09/38|6700
6213|karuna ganguly   |g.m.     |accounts  |05/06/62|6300
1265|s.n. dasgupta    |manager  |sales     |12/09/63|5600
4290|jayant Choudhury |executive|production|07/09/50|6000
6521|lalit chowdury   |director |marketing |26/09/45|8200
3212|shyam saksena    |d.g.m.   |accounts  |12/12/55|6000
3564|sudhir Agarwal   |executive|personnel |06/07/47|7500
```

What does this output represent?

- Is it all lines containing the pattern `director` and `executive`? Clearly no, as there are some lines not containing either one of the patterns.
- Is it all lines starting with first one matching either one of the patters till the last one matching either one of the patterns? No again, as if I go by that logic, one line (`2476|anil aggarwal    |manager  |sales     |01/05/59|5000`) is missing from the output.

I have not been able to clearly deduce how the command `sed -n '/director/,/executive/p' emp.lst` is working? I have gone through the sed man page and have yet been unable to deduce.

How do I approach understanding the working?

For context, I am running `sed` command built into macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 running in Bash version 4.4.

**Note**: I am a `sed` newbie. Please edit any mistake or incorrect terminology that I may have used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Range-Addresses:

> An address range can be specified by specifying two addresses separated by a comma (`,`). An address range matches lines starting from where the first address matches, and continues until the second address matches (inclusively):
>
> ```
> $ seq 10 | sed -n '4,6p'
> 4
> 5
> 6
> ```

Thus `1,2p` does not mean "print lines 1 and 2" but "print all lines between line 1 and line 2". The difference becomes more clear with e.g. `3,7p`, which will not just print line 3 and 7, but lines 3, 4, 5, 6, 7.

`/director/,/executive/p` prints all lines between a starting line (matching `director`) and an ending line (matching `executive`).

In your case, you have two matching ranges (each starting with `director` and ending with `executive`):

```
9876|jai sharma       |director |production|12/03/50|7000
5678|sumit chakrobarty|d.g.m.   |marketing |19/04/43|6000
2365|barun sengupta   |director |personnel |11/05/47|7800
5423|n.k. gupta       |chairman |admin     |30/08/56|5400
1006|chanchal singhvi |director |sales     |03/09/38|6700
6213|karuna ganguly   |g.m.     |accounts  |05/06/62|6300
1265|s.n. dasgupta    |manager  |sales     |12/09/63|5600
4290|jayant Choudhury |executive|production|07/09/50|6000
6521|lalit chowdury   |director |marketing |26/09/45|8200
3212|shyam saksena    |d.g.m.   |accounts  |12/12/55|6000
3564|sudhir Agarwal   |executive|personnel |06/07/47|7500
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your explanation was very helpful and I can now clearly understand the working. I experimented with various placement(s) of `director` and `executive` within the file. man pages although logically precise and concise are generally hard to understand for newbie.

Comment: I have a follow up query and felt it makes more sense to ask here than to write an altogether separate question. Is there a way to select just the first/last/any intermediate one of the many matching blocks?

Answer (score 1):

From `man sed`:

> ```
>      0,addr2
>           Start out in "matched first address"  state,  until  addr2  is  found.
>           This  is  similar  to  1,addr2,  except that if addr2 matches the very
>           first line of input the 0,addr2 form will be at the end of its  range,
>           whereas  the 1,addr2 form will still be at the beginning of its range.
>           This works only when addr2 is a regular expression.
> ```

Not 100% sure if this is the manual section that applies but it looks like you have 2 blocks from "director" to "executive" in your output above. 
There happen to be some other "director" lines between the first "director" and first succeeding "executive".

Comment: That section does not apply. There is no `0,` in OP's code.